# Помогите решить вопрос. Я смотрел видео и по нему делал игру. Видео: "Учим Unity за 1 час! #От Профессионала" автор "Хауди Хо" на моменте 1:16:30

Tags: unity3d, visual-studio-code

Он начал писать код и я его на половину написал и мне самом Unity появлялись много ошибок. Хоть у автора их не было. Код был написан в Visual Studio как и на видео. Код на половину:

using UnityEngine;

public class playermovment : MonoBehaviour
{
public Rigidbody rb;

```
public float runSpeed = 500f;
public float strafeSpeed = 500f;
public float jumpForce = 15f;

protected bool strafeLeft = false;
protected bool strafeRight = false;
protected bool doJump = false;

void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetKey("a"))
    {
        strafeLeft = true;
    } else
    {
        strafeLeft = false;
    }
}
    if(Input.GetKey("d"))
   {
        straferight = true;
    }  else
    {
        strafeRight = false;
   } 

    if(Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
    {
        doJump = true;
    }
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    rb.AddForce(0, 0, runSpeed * Time.deltaTime); 
}
```

Ошибки в Unity:

```
Assets\playermovment.cs(26,9): error CS1519: Invalid token 'if' in class, record, struct, or interface member declaration
Assets\playermovment.cs(26,24): error CS8124: Tuple must contain at least two elements.
Assets\playermovment.cs(38,5): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected
Assets\playermovment.cs(26,25): error CS1031: Type expected
Assets\playermovment.cs(26,25): error CS8124: Tuple must contain at least two elements.
Assets\playermovment.cs(26,25): error CS1026: ) expected
Assets\playermovment.cs(26,25): error CS1519: Invalid token '"d"' in class, record, struct, or interface member declaration
Assets\playermovment.cs(28,25): error CS1519: Invalid token '=' in class, record, struct, or interface member declaration
Assets\playermovment.cs(29,12): error CS8803: Top-level statements must precede namespace and type declarations.
Assets\playermovment.cs(29,12): error CS8641: 'else' cannot start a statement.
Assets\playermovment.cs(29,12): error CS1003: Syntax error, '(' expected
Assets\playermovment.cs(29,12): error CS1525: Invalid expression term 'else'
Assets\playermovment.cs(29,12): error CS1026: ) expected
Assets\playermovment.cs(29,12): error CS1002: ; expected
Assets\playermovment.cs(38,5): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected
```

Comment: Не нужно бездумно переписывать код, нужно его понимать. В приведённом вами коде лишняя закрывающаяся фигурная скобка.

Answer (score 0):

Должно сработать:

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody Body;

    public float RunSpeed = 500f;
    public float StrafeSpeed = 500f;
    public float JumpForce = 15f;

    protected bool StrafeLeft = false;
    protected bool StrafeRight = false;
    protected bool DoJump = false;
    
    void Update()
    {
        this.StrafeLeft = Input.GetKey("a");
        this.StrafeRight = Input.GetKey("d");
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
        {
            this.DoJump = true;
        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        this.Body.AddForce(0, 0, this.RunSpeed * Time.deltaTime); 
    }
}
```